# Are there infinitely many instances of this sum of primes squared?

Tags: number-theory

$2^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+11^2=208$ is the least example in which the sum of the squares of the first $k$ primes is divisible by the prime $p_{k+1}$, that in this particular case is $13$. Could you find other examples of such primes and give an heuristic how much frequent these primes are? Are there infinitely many $(p_1)^2+(p_2)^2+(p_3)^2+(p_4)^2+...+(p_k)^2$ which are divisible by $p_{k+1}$?

Comment: @Peter could you find other examples or do you believe it is too hard to find out?

Comment: As with one of your earlier questions, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3161810/are-there-infinitely-many-instances-where-the-n-th-prime-divides-the-sum-of-th , heuristics suggest divisibility occurs with probability $1/p_{k+1}$, so the expected number of occurrences is $\sum 1/p$, which diverges (slowly!).

Comment: In the meantime, here are the results for $\sum_{n=1}^m \rho_n^2 \bmod \rho_{m+1}$, where $\rho_n$ is the $n$th prime number. The only solutions for $n\leq 200$ are $n=5, \rho_n = 11$ (like yours) and $n=16, \rho_n = 53$ which equates to $225\times 59$. ![Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hn25.jpg)

Comment: @Infiaria for $n=5$ and $\rho_n=11$ this equates to $16\cdot 13$. So always $m^2\cdot \rho_{n+1}$?

Comment: So far I have the cases $(k,p_{k+1}) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 13 \\
 16 & 59 \\
 11155 & 118259 \\
 16547 & 182603 \\
\end{array}
\right)$.

Comment: @user15994  I was just about to post those.  There are no others for primes $\lt 10^8$.  Note that in the last two cases, the sum of squares is *not* a square times the next prime.

Comment: @FredH Intesting.  I was only in the process of checking cases for primes $<10^6$, and I hadn't bothered with the check for sum of squares a square time the next prime.

Comment: No further solutions upto $10^9$